# Stream builder getting data from cloud firestore even when page is not on view

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 pages.

Page One is use to add data to cloud firestore
Page Two is used to query those documents'

When i add data to cloud firestore, its causing me one write and one read, even when the page is not on the front view.

How do i prevent causing document reads when the page is not in view?

Comment: Maybe you can share some code of your pages ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `.listen()`? Then you have to [`.cancel()`](https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/#9-dispose) at the [`dispose()`](https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/#9-dispose) method of your `State` object.

Comment: i am using stream builder.   Stream data;

  override
  void initState() {
    data = Firestore.instance
        .collection('workers')
        .where('name', isEqualTo: widget.name)
        .snapshots();
    super.initState();
  } I am trying to put like data.dispose() or data.cancle in the overrider dispose but its showing me red